# problem while deploying a javafx app in netbeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, deployment, java-8

I followed tutorials on deploying a `JavaFX` from `NetBeans` application.
but after the deployment, I found a `.exe` the file that does not work properly on another pc.

I've installed `Wix` and `inno` setup `6`, I put them in the path and I entered in the `project ->package as->exe` installer I've added this code in the `build.xml` file :

```xml
    <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
           <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" 
                     nativeBundles="all"
                     outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
              <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
              <fx:resources>
                  <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="DarinnAPP.jar"/>
              </fx:resources>
              <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
          </fx:deploy>          
     </target>
```

I want to have an executable file to install the application in another pc.
I would be very grateful if you helped me find the solution.

Comment: The other Computer needs a Java JRE/JDK